# How to update content and right bar together from custom module?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a slider and I want to display that slider to right side and content together . 
In my bellow code it displays only in content .

```
<layout version="0.1.0">   
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss">
            <js>css/dreamztech/productslider/style.css</js>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>  
  <customeslider_index_index>   
    <reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>   
    <reference name="right">  
      <block type="customeslider/index" name="customeslider_list" template="customeslider/list.phtml"/>   
    </reference>  
    <reference name="content">  
      <block type="customeslider/index" name="customeslider_slider" template="customeslider/index.phtml"/>   
    </reference>      
  </customeslider_index_index>   
</layout>
```

I also tried

```
<customeslider_index_index>   
<reference name="root">   
  <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>   
</reference>
<reference name="content">  
  <block type="customeslider/index" name="customeslider_slider" template="customeslider/index.phtml"/>   
</reference>       
<reference name="right"> 
   <block type="customeslider/index" name="customeslider_list" before="-">
     <action method="setTemplate" >
                    <template>customeslider/list.phtml</template> 
     </action>
   </block>              
</reference>
```

Still same issue

Answer (score 0):

use `before="-"`

```
 <reference name="right">  
      <block type="customeslider/index" name="customeslider_list" template="customeslider/list.phtml" before="-"/>   
    </reference>
```

or try

```
<reference name="right"> 
   <block type="customeslider/index" name="customeslider_list" before="-">
     <action method="setTemplate" >
                    <template>customeslider/list.phtml</template> 
     </action>
   </block>              
</reference>
```

then check make sure you clear you **cache** or delete **var/cache** folder

Comment: No . same result . My Cache are disabled . Thank you for your comment

Comment: @DebasisChakraborty check the **template name** is correct  and make sure it is **current theme or base theme**

Comment: @DebasisChakraborty added another solution try that. **It is  tested**

Comment: no... If I remove content than right panel is coming but if I put together than only content part is coming .

Comment: @DebasisChakraborty add `content` reference first then `right`  make sure their `name` are different.

Comment: same issue update my ques with my last try as you said